# Segmentation fault on Debian PHP5.3.3-7

Tags: php, debugging, segmentation-fault

I just started getting segmentation faults in php. It started yesterdag evening. I didnt change any of my code but the amount of data it has to handle is increased in size so it could be a memory problem.

Command :php console.php retrieve all

```
!!RetrieveCommand loaded.
@@time = 1306408225
[[ opkotingent
?? fetching data
?? data fetch succesfull
Segmentation fault
```

GDB Output :

```
Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
ZEND_FE_FETCH_SPEC_VAR_HANDLER (execute_data=0x7ffff094bc48) at /build/buildd-php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze1-amd64-ihNnkV/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend.h:381
381 /build/buildd-php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze1-amd64-ihNnkV/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend.h: No such file or directory.
in /build/buildd-php5_5.3.3-7+squeeze1-amd64-ihNnkV/php5-5.3.3/Zend/zend.h
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be the result of running out of memory. If you're sure it's not running out of memory then you may have hit a bug. It will be exceedingly difficult to further debug without source code.